# Cannot connect to remote Ubuntu desktop

Tags: networking, server, firewall, vnc, xrdp

I have a remote server with Ubuntu 16.04 and I used to connect to it remotely using XRDP or VNC and it was very smooth until recently. Suddenly after a while, XRDP and VNC stopped responding and I face timeout when I try to connect to remote desktop services (SSH is still available).

I have tried restarting both the VNC and XRDP services, rebooting the server, uninstall/reinstalling VNC and XRDP with no luck. Then, I guess the problem might come from the firewall, blocking the ports. I turned off the firewall (sudo ufw disable) but it doesn't help. Then I checked the open ports on the server and found that the XRDP and VNC are listening on proper ports. Here is the output of the netstat command:

[image: Here is the output of the netstat command]

With the firewall still disabled, I checked whether the XRDP port (3389) is open or not using [ping.eu](http://ping.eu/port-chk/), and surprisingly it said the port is closed! I turned the firewall on again, added port 3389 to the whitelist (sudo ufw allow 3389) and repeated the procedure but ping.eu still says the port is closed. I'm pretty confused now and I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: Is there a router at the remote end, between you and the remote server, that could have the ports closed?

Comment: I don't think so. I can establish remote desktop connection to another server in the same subnet.

Comment: The "unable to resolve host" message from `sudo` suggests you've messed with your `/etc/hosts` file - I'm not sure if it's related, but it might be worth fixing that at least to rule it out

Comment: That does not answer @Arronical's question, as there might be some port forwarding or firewall rules for one server and not for the other. If you have  working SSH access, you could try [X2Go](http://wiki.x2go.org) instead of RDP or VNC.